# Firebase: Can user be analysed individually?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application in Firebase. Earlier i was using parse. Parse creates an install object on installation which is then added to the server database.

I have not been able to find anything similar in case of Firebase. So does Firebase has any database with installation properties like the date installed, updated, timezone and version?

Comment: What is your point of using firebase? Do you want to use it for push notifcation or database?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides developers to analyze the user data, FCM Analytics has been built so wonderfully that you can get every small detail like :
1.the count of different versions of the app installed
2.the device model names.
3.the different OS versions which the app is running on
4.geographical count of the app installs in various countries and many many details

It also provides a facility for crash reporting,by simply adding a dependency in your build.gradle, developers can get a detailed crash report and the full stack trace with line numbers.

Developers can also set something called the user property with which they can analyze the different user usage patterns.

And many more features, all in one single console.
For better understanding you can go through the docs for FCM from the below link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

Comment: By integrating FCM in your app has far more benefits that just that using it for push notifications

Comment: I do understand the capability of Firebase. But what i am saying is if Firebase can provide all that information on an individual level. For example: lets say a user is using version 1 of my application. So can i get to know which user is that (probably identified by the token id). Right now the information is aggregated. Ofcourse i can get that information from the user itself and post it to my database. But just wanted to know if Firebase does that for me to avoid rendundancy

Comment: i think you can by passing the userid of the users you have stored in the app as a Firebase UserProperty something like this   FcmAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserProperty("userID", ""+ userID); and once you have done this, Go to the firebase console page-->Analytics-->UserProperties-->NewUserproperty-->the name should be the same as the key u are passing in your app i.e. in this case "userID" and give a short description-->Select Add Filter--->UserProperty-->scrolldown you will find your userID-->enter your userID--> Once the filter is set-->Select dashboard there you can see your version

Comment: I tried doing as you said but now when I go to analytics-> add filter, it shows userID but there are no suggested values. I am using token as the userID. Any help?

Comment: when you select the userID, it allows you to type in the userID. So if u want to analyse the data about a particular user, since you are the developer u will get the userID, type in the userID as the filter and see the data.